# HTTPS connection with wampserver for "Facebook for WordPress" plugin

Tags: plugins, facebook, https

I have installed Wordpress 3.9.1 on wampserver2.2e-php5.3.13-httpd2.2.22-mysql5.5.24-x64. Then I installed the Facebook Plugin (1.5.5). I created a Facebook app and than I wanted to enter the credentials in the Facebook plugin. I get the following error message:

> Your server does not support communication with Facebook servers over
>   HTTPS.
>
> Facebook application functionality such as posting to your Facebook
>   Timeline requires a HTTPS connection to Facebook servers

What can I do to allow the HTTPS connection? Is this a configuration problem with wampserver?

PS: I don't know where to put this topic. Is it serverfault, superuser or wordpress? I put it on wordpress because it is the main topic here.

**Edit:**
The error message is thrown through this piece of code:

```
// notify of lack of HTTPS
if ( ! wp_http_supports( array( 'ssl' => true ) ) )
    add_action( 'admin_notices', array( 'Facebook_Application_Settings', 'admin_notice' ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine this is because `php_curl` extension hasn't been enabled in wamp. You can try to enable curl and then restart wamp.

If you have a tray icon for wamp you can left click on the tray icon, choose PHP -> PHP Extensions and enable `php_curl`. Then left click the icon again and this time select Restart All Services.

Or to do it manually:

1. Navigate to WAMP\bin\php(your version of php)\
2. Edit php.ini
3. Search for curl, uncomment extension=php_curl.dll
4. Navigate to WAMP\bin\Apache(your version of apache)\bin\
5. Edit php.ini
6. Search for curl, uncomment extension=php_curl.dll
7. Save both
8. Restart WAMP

Comment: I tried both ways but the error message still exists. Do you have more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in fact that `curl` was not loaded. Instead something like `WP_HTTP_streams` was used. But it seems that the `curl` dll for Windows delivered with the package needs to be fixed. I used the information from this [thread](http://www.o3n.org/2012/06/wamp-server-2-2-windows-7-64-bit-and-curl-also-for-windows-8/):

> 1. Setup wamp.
> 2. From wamp icon select PHP > PHP extensions > php_curl  (it needs to be checked)
> 3. Extract php_curl.dll from the [zip](http://www.mediafire.com/file/qwgdzgccthzwc15/php_curl-5.3.13-VC9-x64.zip) and copy it to PHP extension directory (mine is c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\ext)
> 4. Restart all services from the wamp menu
> 5. Go to localhost and click phpinfo() link and see that curl is there…

You can download the zip file (php_curl-5.3.13-VC9-x64.zip) from [here](http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/). Now everything is working fine and curl is also available in the `phpinfo` (localhost/?phpinfo=1).